# UI5 - Value Help via OData annotation

Tags: odata, sapui5

I've created a value help annotation for field form/CompanyCode, see metadata below:

```
<EntityType sap:content-version="1" Name="shBukrs">
 <Key>
  <PropertyRef Name="Bukrs"/>
 </Key>
 <Property Name="Bukrs" sap:label="Company Code" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4" sap:creatable="false" Nullable="false"/>
 <Property Name="Butxt" sap:filterable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:label="Company Name" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="25" sap:creatable="false" Nullable="false"/>
 <Property Name="Ort01" sap:filterable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:label="City" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="25" sap:creatable="false" Nullable="false"/>
 <Property Name="Waers" sap:filterable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:label="Currency" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="5" sap:creatable="false" Nullable="false" sap:semantics="currency-code"/>
</EntityType>

<Annotation Term="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1.ValueList">
   <Record>
    <PropertyValue String="shBukrsSet" Property="CollectionPath"/>
    <PropertyValue Property="SearchSupported" Bool="true"/>
    <PropertyValue Property="Parameters">
     <Collection>
      <Record Type="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1.ValueListParameterOut">
       <PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty" PropertyPath="CompanyCode"/>
       <PropertyValue String="Bukrs" Property="ValueListProperty"/>
      </Record>
      <Record Type="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1.ValueListParameterDisplayOnly">
       <PropertyValue String="Butxt" Property="ValueListProperty"/>
      </Record>
     </Collection>
    </PropertyValue>
   </Record>
 </Annotation>
</Annotations>
```

I've added the field to the form:

```
<smartField:SmartLabel labelFor="idCompanyCode"/>
<smartField:SmartField value="{CompanyCode}" id="idCompanyCode"/>
```

but the value help is not attached to the field on the form (no value help button)...

Anyone any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Solved... target service name was missing:

Old:

```
<Annotation Term="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1.ValueList">
```

New:

```
<Annotation Term="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1.ValueList" Target="<service>">
```

Please make sure that you use the Registered Service name as Target value.